# Mysql Query SUM adding each to eachother result?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if my question makes no sense.  Not sure if we can do this with mysql only.  Lets say I have this query:

```
SELECT SUM(win) * 100 as win_profit, date, uid FROM `tips` WHERE uid = 60 AND placed = 1 GROUP by date
```

This would obviously get the sum of the win column each day that is in the database.

Lets say the database had:

```
|___win___|____date____|
|   10    | 2014-04-16 |
|   10    | 2014-04-16 |
|   10    | 2014-04-17 |
|   10    | 2014-04-18 |
|   10    | 2014-04-18 |
|   10    | 2014-04-18 |
|   10    | 2014-04-19 |
|   10    | 2014-04-19 |
|   10    | 2014-04-19 |
```

This would result:

```
20
10
30
30
```

How can I get it to result so each adds up, mysql query only. So the result would be:

```
20
30
60
90
```

Comment: don't apologize, it's an interesting question. not sure if/how it can be done, though. as you kind of suggest, it would be easy to create that functionality outside mysql once the values are returned

Comment: well if it can't be done with mysql only. i would love to see how it would be done in php as well.  But I am using the mysql loop as a Json output, but I can do it from the php later.

Comment: loop over the results and do $sum += $row[0]

Comment: awesome, that was easy enough.

Comment: BTW, What's the PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all distinct dates, and `LEFT JOIN` to find the sum of all values up to that date; I kept the 100 multiplier from your sample query, but you need to remove it to get a result matching your desired result.

```
SELECT 100 * SUM(b.win), a.date 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM `tips`) a
LEFT JOIN tips b ON a.date >= b.date
GROUP BY a.date
ORDER BY a.date
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc50a/1).

Comment: thanks, this seems like a nice result. I'll test this now to use mysql only.

Answer (score 0):

This could be another way to do it...

```
SET @full_sum=0;
SELECT @full_sum+SUM(win) as win_profit, date as this_date, uid, 
@full_sum:=(SELECT @full_sum+SUM(win) 
            FROM `testing` WHERE uid = 60 
            GROUP by date HAVING date=this_date) 
FROM `testing` WHERE uid = 60 GROUP by date;
```